# wordpress order custom posts

Tags: wordpress

What am i doing wrong...

It's something stupid.

I want to order my posts but regardless of what i put in order and orderby, nothing works! GRRR

```
<?php  
        $postCount = 0;   

        remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'replace_ellipsis');    
        remove_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length');

        add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'replace_ellipsis2');    
        add_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length2');

        $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'news', 
            'posts_per_page' => 9999,
            'order' => 'ASC',
        );                                                       

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $postCount++; 
?>

            <div class = "anArticle" style = "<?php if(!$postCount % 3 == 1){ echo 'margin-right:0px;'; } ?>" onclick = "location.href='<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>';">
                <div class = "title"><a href = "<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if(!get_field('short_title')){echo limit_length(get_the_title(), 48);}else{echo get_field('short_title') . '...';} ?></a></div>
                <div class = "theDate"><? the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></div>                                                                                               
                <?php if(!get_field('caption')){the_excerpt();}else{the_field('caption'); echo '...';} ?> 
                <div class = "readMore"><a href = "<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">Read more... </a></div>  
            </div> 
<?php
        endwhile;
?>
```

Anything catching your eye as being stupid?

Anything you know that can usually stop posts from ordering correctly?

Comment: Which field do you want to sort on? try 'orderby' => 'ID'

Comment: the date so 'orderby' => 'date' is something i already tried..but i sussed it out. i needed to use get_posts instead

Answer (score 2):

You're not specifying a field to order by--you're trying to simply say "in ascending order" without saying what field to use.

Change it from this:

```
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'news', 
        'posts_per_page' => 9999,
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );
```

To this:

```
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'news', 
        'posts_per_page' => 9999,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
    );
```

and see what happens.

Comment: doesnt work.. alas i have sussed it out just now (see my answer)

Comment: @JamesT, I still encourage you to select an order by clause. Not specifying one is absurd at best.

Comment: Cool... i must admit, i forgot to put it in this post :)

Answer (score 0):

needed to use get_posts

```
<?php      
    global $post;                                        
    $postCount = 0;  
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'news', 'order' => 'DESC' );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );                      

    remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'replace_ellipsis');    
    remove_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length');

    add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'replace_ellipsis2');    
    add_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length2');

    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);

        $postCount++;

    ?>     
        <div class = "anArticle" style = "<?php if(!$postCount % 3 == 1){ echo 'margin-right:0px;'; } ?>" onclick = "location.href='<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>';">
            <div class = "title"><a href = "<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if(!get_field('short_title')){echo limit_length(get_the_title(), 48);}else{echo get_field('short_title') . '...';} ?></a></div>
            <div class = "theDate"><? the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></div>                                                                                               
            <?php if(!get_field('caption')){the_excerpt();}else{the_field('caption'); echo '...';} ?> 
            <div class = "readMore"><a href = "<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">Read more... </a></div>  
        </div> 
    <?php endforeach;
?>
```